# How to point to a specific file when moving 2 times at the same time? Unix

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to move(using mv) multiple files from Folder A to Folder B. I'm also writing the (File Name, File Path, File Created Date, File Size) to a separate .txt file.

My problem is: Sometimes files may have different permissions and when you try to move a file with incorrect permissions, the script will run but the file won't actually get moved. Now I want to only write the (File Name, File Path, File Created Date, File Size) of the files that did get moved from Folder A to Folder B.

For example:

Folder A contains : File1, File2, File3

After the script

Folder B contains : File1, File2

".txt" file should contain metadata of only File1 and File2.

I can't point directly at Folder B because over time more files will get moved into this folder and the .txt file should only contain the metadata of the latest files that got moved.

My current script still grabs everything within FolderA, I just want to be able to grab the ones that got moved.

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
#!/bin/bash

base_dir="FolderA"

target_dir="FolderB"


find $base_dir -type f -name '*837*' -printf '%C@\t%p\n'| sort -nk1 | cut -f2- | while IFS= read -r file;do

year="$(date -d "$(stat -c %z "$file")" +%Y)"

month="$(date -d "$(stat -c %z "$file")" +%m)"

day="$(date -d "$(stat -c %z "$file")" +%d)"

mv --backup=t "$file" "$target_dir/$year/$month/$day";

echo "$(basename "$file")"  >> "$target_dir/test_file.txt";

echo | stat -c %z "$file" >> "$target_dir/test_file.txt";

echo     "$file"  >> "$target_dir/test_file.txt";

echo     "$target_dir/$year/$month/$day" >> "$target_dir/test_file.txt";

echo | stat -c %s "$file" >> "$target_dir/test_file.txt";


done
```

Comment: You could catch the return code of the move command like `ret=$?` and then test it to see if it's `0` (successfuly) or something else.

Comment: I would suggest using something else than Bash for this, if possible. Not hard to do with e.g. Python :)

Comment: @JNevill But if i drop 2 files (1 with the correct permissions and 1 without), how can i grab the metadata of the one that does have the correct permissions?

Comment: You test that return code and if it's `0` then you capture the metadata, if it's anything but that, then you move on to your next file without capturing the metadata. Something like `if [ $ret -eq 0 ]; then`...

Comment: Are you moving files from a source directory recursively or not?

Comment: `ret=$?` is generally a bad practice if you just want to know if it's zero or nonzero. Better to use `if yourcommand; then` instead of `yourcommand; ret=$?; if [ $ret -eq 0 ]; then`.

Comment: @EricHong, ...btw, `>>...` over and over is generally bad form. If you put your code in a block, you can redirect the entire block at once with `>"$target_dir/test_file.txt`, opening the output file only once when the block starts, instead of re-opening it for each command, and closing it and flushing it when that individual command completes.

Comment: Also, if you have a new enough version of bash, you'll get much better performance using the shell's built-in date formatting. `file_time=$(stat -c %Z -- "$file"); printf -v year '%(%Y)T' "$file_time"; printf -v month '%(%M)T' "$file_time"; printf -v day '%(%D)T' "$file_time"` only runs *one* fork() for the single `stat` command, vs the original code needing at least six (three to run `/usr/bin/stat`, three for `/usr/bin/date`).

Comment: ...that said, if you're only trying to find new files, don't use this kind of script in the first place; there are special-purpose tools like [`incron`](https://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=doc&lang=en) built for the job.

Comment: Following up on working with dates, it's generally better to read the date only once, regardless of the method, _then_ parse it into its parts: `IFS='- ' read -r year month day _ <<< "$(stat -c %z "$file")" ` or as shown in Charles Duffy's comment. The reason for this is that the time or date could change between calls if you make multiple calls.

Answer (score 0):

> How to point to a specific file when moving 2 times at the same time?

Since you aren't moving multiple files at the same time, but rather one after the other in the `while` loop, this question is groundless.

> the .txt file should only contain the metadata of the latest files that got moved.

To sum up the relevant suggestions for the *move* part from Charles Duffy and to further simplify the date handling (since you don't need year, month and day separately):

```
… | while IFS= read -r file; do

    date=$(date -d "$(stat -c %z "$file")" +%Y/%m/%d)
    target_path="$target_dir/$date"
    mkdir -p "$target_path" # Wasn't this missing?
    if mv --backup=t "$file" "$target_path"; then
        stat --printf="${file##*/}\n%z\n$file\n$target_path\n%s\n" "$target_path/${file##*/}"
    fi

done >"$target_dir/test_file.txt"
```

This also makes use of Bash's [*Parameter Expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) `${file##*/}` instead of `basename`.